# Schedule Python - Overlapping functions

Tags: python, automated-tests, schedule

I am trying to run 2 functions at different times, one after another.
The first function contains while loop in it (without break, since I want to keep it running until the next function comes)
However, when the next schedule comes, it doesn't run the second function and stuck in the 1st one.

I have tried to add sys.exit() but it doesn't even go into that function

```
import schedule
import sys
import time

def do_complete_automation():
    while True:
        print()
        print("do_complete_automation()")
        time.sleep(5)

def exit1():
    print("exit")
    sys.exit()

schedule.every().sunday.at('16:42').do(do_complete_automation)
schedule.every().sunday.at('16:42:30').do(exit1)
schedule.every().sunday.at('16:42:35').do(do_complete_automation)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

It should print "exit"

Comment: use module `threading` to run it in separated thread.

Comment: `do_complete_automation()` never ends, so once it starts running, your program never has a chance to do anything else.  (Even if `exit1()` were called, it would exit the program altogether.)

Comment: @furas could you give an example on how to do it?

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=do_complete_automation).start()`. Doc: [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)